# Crystal Report cannot display fields

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I want to ask how to display the fields in Crystal report from different tables. I have this line of code:

```
Dim rpt as CrystalReport1
Dim d as String
Dim rptView as CrystalReportViewer


d="select * from tbl_loanledger where mem_id='" & d &"'" 
rpt.SetDataSource(d)
rptView.showDialog(rpt)
```

and failed to display the data in the field.
Whats wrong with my code? or do I have to do something else?

Answer (score 1):

How have you designed the report is more important. If you have designed the report and put the fields in appropriate sections (header, group, details, footer etc) and then binding the data source, it should work.

The other suggestion is not to use * in the query, but defining the column names explicitly like `select col1, col2, col3 from tbl_loanledger where mem_id='" & d &"'"`

In the code `rpt.SetDataSource(d)` you are setting d, the querystring as the data source. This is not the correct way.

Define a `DataSet` and fill it with the desired data in your VB code. Nest in the `SetDataSource`, pass the `DataSet` as the parameter.

Comment: I placed the fields on the right section. How to bind datasource?. Thank you so much :)